# Cannot Add People to Custom Audience

Tags: java, facebook, spring, restfb, facebook-ads-api

I can successfully create a blank custom audience, but when I try to add people I am unsuccessful. It is weird because I get success messages back from facebook, but when I go to power editor to view, the audience says "No File Uploaded". Even after waiting for hours, nothing happens.

I have tried using both the current migration and the October first migration, and for the current migration I receive "true" and for the October first migration I receive an audience_details object that has num_received=9000 (the number of audience members). Has anyone experienced similar problems? Below is my code and the JSON I'm sending to fb.

```
public Boolean addPeopleToAudience(String customAudienceId, JSONObject payloadJsonObject) throws FSSocialAuthException, JSONException {
    //october 1st migration (with return type CustomAudience class)
    //return getSessionClient().publish("/"+customAudienceId+"/users", CustomAudience.class, Parameter.with("payload", payloadJsonObject.toString()));

    //current migration (with return type Boolean)
    return getSessionClient().publish("/"+customAudienceId+"/", Boolean.class, Parameter.with("users", payloadJsonObject.get("users").toString()), Parameter.with("hash_type", "sha256"));
}
```

JsonObject being sent to FB:

```
{"users":"[{\"email_hash\":\"f1904cf1a9d73a55fa5de0ac8279\"},{\"email_hash\":\"f1904cf1a9d73a55fa50bdcd0866552bb79\"}...]}
```

The json is converted to a string before the call, and I get "true" response from facebook.
I have tried using a "/"+customAudienceId+"/users" endpoint for the current migration, but I receive an oAuth error.

Thank you for any insight/experiences you have to share!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app settings migration, the new migration wasn't switched on. It works after using new migration and toggling that on.

Comment: Which library you are using? can yo please some example for creating ad and adding audience.